# Equilateral $\triangle ABC$ , minimum of PA+PB+PC where line on P

Tags: geometry

$ A( 1, \sqrt 3 ) , B( 0,0), C(2,0)  $

P is on the line $x =  \frac{ 1} 3 $

Find minimum of $PA + PB +  PC $

---

It looks like fermat point , but point P is bounded some line.

Comment: Have you made experiments with Geogebra for example ?

Comment: $(1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}) ?$

Comment: @Narasimhan : P must be on the line $x=1/3$.

Comment: I find the y-coordiante of $P$ $\sim 0.3330382$ which is $\sqrt{3}$ times the root of the decic polynmial $$59049z^{10}-196830z^9+321489z^8-384912z^7+349434z^6\\
-191484z^5
+55218z^4-17248z^3+3805z^2-950z+125$$ near $0.2$. I don't know anyway to decompose this polynomial further, so it is possible the final answer cannot be expressed in terms of radicals.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a nice way to do this, what I tried is to just get the distance function, $$f(y)= \sqrt{\frac{4}{9}+(y-\sqrt{3})^2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{9}+y^2}+\sqrt{\frac{25}{9}+y^2}$$ where $P=\left(\frac{1}{3}, y\right)$. Then, $$f'(y)=\frac{y-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{9}+(y-\sqrt{3})^2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{9}+y^2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{\frac{25}{9}+y^2}}.$$ Now, I guess solving $f'(y)$ is equivalent to solving the polynomial given by @achille hui in the comments and wolfram alpha gives $y ≈ 0.33303820798192625734044202$ which means the minimum value is $\min{f(y)}≈3.72055$.

Comment: rationalizing $f'(y) = 0$ and substitute $y = \sqrt{3}z$ will give us a dodedic polynomial in $z$  It has a quadratic factor but that factor doesn't give us the minimum we seek. So yes, solving $f'(y) = 0$ is essentially equivalent to solving the polynomial I mentioned in comment.

Comment: Is there any way to solve it with synthetic geometry?